# Android: Edit_Text multiline but not for the Hint

Tags: android, android-edittext

just wanna ask you if it's possible to do

```
  android:inputType="textMultiLine" & android:maxLines="5"
```

with the hint just having

```
  android:maxLines="1"
```

due to smaller Size

Due to Localization the text can be longer.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

yes it's possible but with cheating.

In first, set your maxLine to 1. The idea is to set the maxLine at 5 when the hint disappear. You can know it when the focus is up on your EditText with an `setOnFocusChangeListener`

Set your `setOnFocusChangeListener` like it :

```
    EditText ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.MY_EDIT_TEXT);
    ed.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean isFocused) {
            if (isFocused)
                ((EditText)view).setMaxLines(5);
            else
                ((EditText)view).setMaxLines(1);
        }
    });
```

Good Luck

**EDIT**

I thought that the hint disappear when the focus was on it but the hint disappear only when a text is added.

The new solution for fix this problem is to add a listener on the contain of your EditText. The bad point (if it is) is that you must make your EditText final.

```
    final EditText ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.MY_EDIT_TEXT);
    ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (count == 0)
                ed.setMaxLines(1);
            else
                ed.setMaxLines(5);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but it didnt really work .. both of your suggestions ... can not understand why as well ...

Answer (score 0):

@Clément Chameyrat is a good answer, you can improve his first answer by checking if the editeText's text is empty or not.
If the hint is displayed, getText() would not return anythig, so use this fact in your code in order to figure out when hint is displayed or not
:

```java
  EditText ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.MY_EDIT_TEXT);
    ed.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean isFocused) {
            String text = ((EditText)view).getText().toString();
            if (isFocused && !text.equals(''))
                ((EditText)view).setMaxLines(5);
            else if (!isFocused && text.equals(''))
                ((EditText)view).setMaxLines(1);
        }
    });
```